# React Native - Apollo client and partial fetch in multiple queries

Tags: reactjs, react-native, apollo-client, react-apollo, graphql-js

I would like to know if Apollo `client.query` can handle multiple query and fetch only missing data, which are not in cache.

Client is defined like this:

```js
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/react-hooks";

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

and sample query like this:

```js
import { gql } from "@apollo/react-hooks";

export const GET_CLASS = gql`
  query GetClass($courseId: ID!, $lessonId: ID!){ 
    course(id: $courseId) {
      id
      title
      author
      description
    }
    lesson(id: $lessonId) {
      id
      title
      teacher
    }
  }
`
```

When I call my first query:

```js
client.query({
        query: GET_CLASS,
        variables: { courseId:111, lessonId:222, },
      })
```

I see on backend requests for *course* with id 111 and *lesson* with id 222, which is OK. When I recall query with the same variables, data are returned from cache (no request on backend), which is OK.

But when I then call this query:

```js
client.query({
        query: GET_CLASS,
        variables: { courseId:333, lessonId:222, },
      })
```

I see on backend requests for *course* with id 333 and also *lesson* with id 222.

I thought that Apollo will handle this and it will get:

- *course* with id 333 from backend
- *lesson* with id 222 from cache

I tried `returnPartialData:true`, but it just got stuck.

I tried many combinations and it looks like, that if there are missing data for at least one object, it will send whole query to backend.

Is it possible to tell client, that he should request only for missing data from query?

**Note**: I don't want to query *lesson* and *course* separately. This is just a small sample from more complex queries.

Comment: Could you change cache behavior in special query such as: `const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_DOGS, {
  fetchPolicy: "no-cache" 
});`? I mean you can change `fetchPolicy` to bypassing cache.

Comment: But if you mean, you want to refresh cache after a mutation, you can use `refetchQueries` after `useMutation`. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#refetching-after-update